# Consumir Json, problema com Cors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Bom dia!

Estou realizando uma consulta (via jQuery e Json) na API do Mercadobitcoin, mas sempre recebo um erro no retorno. Ao inspecionar, consta que há uma falha pelo metodo CORS.
Verifiquei a documentação, há um aviso "os métodos têm CORS".
Procurei em vários lugares mas ainda não achei como resolver a consulta sem precisar de algo por parte do server-side.

Doc da API: https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/api-doc/

Estou utilizando uma consulta simples como:

```
$.get( "http://meusite.com/", function( data )
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo funcional (verifique o console) de utilização da API: https://pastebin.com/xpr8DnMB

Segundo o DOC, o URL é este: `https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/<coin>/<method>/`, onde **coin** pode ser **BTC**, **LTC** ou **BCH**; onde **method** pode ser **ticker**, **orderbook** ou **trades**

Answer (score 0):

Se os métodos possuem CORS habilitado em server side uma pequenas mudança na sua requisição AJAX pode resolver tudo, você deve adicionar a linha `crossDomain: true` no header da sua requisição.

Segue um exemplo de uma requisição ajax utilizando **CORS true** no cabeçalho:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://meusite.com/",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(response)
            alert(resp.status);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```